# Why does `bool b = 2` work well but `bool b = {2}` yield a warning of narrowing conversion?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, narrowing

Using the `{}` initializer in `C++11` to initialize `bool b = {2}` yields the following warning message:

```
warning: narrowing conversion of ‘2’ from ‘int’ to ‘bool’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
```

However, using the old style `bool b = 2` has no such problem. What is the reason behind this?

---

Update: I compiled the code using `g++ -std=c++11` and it gave me the warning. If I add the option `-pedantic-errors`, the warning becomes an error.

Comment: When I really think about this, although we are used to thinking about `anything not 0` and `0` as `true` and `false` as far as I can tell the standard gives you no promise that `true` and `false` are `1` and `0` respectively, it just guarantees conversions. So if you are going to use a literal then use `true` and `false`, which will never be a narrowing conversion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Narrowing a data type in an initialization-list makes your c++11 program ill formed, in this situation the compiler can either give a warning or keep going.

Interestingly enough you can actually change it to `bool b = {1}` and there is no warning, I'm assuming because the value of a bool is guaranteed to convert to 0 and 1 in integral types.

Here is a standard quote confirming the error.

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
>   — from a floating-point type to an integer type, or
>   — from long double to double or float, or from double to float, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion is within the range of values  that can be represented (even if it cannot be represented exactly), or
>   — from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to a floating-point type, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion will fit into the target type and will produce the original value when converted back to the original type, or
>   — from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion will fit into the target type and will produce the original value when converted back to the original type.
>   As indicated above, such conversions are not allowed at the top level in list-initializations

Comment: The `bool b = {2}` was legal since C++98 and narrowing conversion were not errors in C++98. Making it an error in C++11 would constitute a breaking change. Did they really do it in C++11? I truly don't know, but I suspect that in case of `bool b = {2}` it is not an error. This is probably why a mere warning is issued in this case. (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: @AndreyT it is an error on clang at least, on gcc haven't checked

Comment: OK, it looks like it should be an error indeed. They probably thought that the `{}` syntax was used very rarely to initialize scalars (if at all), so making it an error would not break much of legacy code.

Comment: I compiled the code using `g++ -std=c++11` and it gave me a warning instead of an error

Comment: @TianZhou should be an error, are you sure the compiler isn't ignoring the -std=c++11 option

Comment: @TianZhou it would say it, what is your compiler version

Comment: @AndreyT Oh I just added that option and the warning became an error!

Comment: @aaronman: The value of `bool` in C++ is not guaranteed to be `0` or `1`. It is guaranteed to convert to `0` or `1` when converted to integral types. Meanwhile, the internal representation of `bool` can be anything.

Comment: @AndreyT fair enough, fixed

Comment: @TianZhou it's not too, old IDT (don't use gcc myself) but as the standard quote in the deleted answer said the error is indeed correct, I'll put a standard quote in my answer too

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour clang produces an error my gcc isn't up to date enough to error

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I'll amend my answer

Comment: @aaronman I may be incorrect on the ill-formed part, let me reread more carefully.

Comment: @aaronman Okay it seems like it is not clear [what a compiler is required to do with an ill-formed program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805394/what-is-the-c-compiler-required-to-do-with-ill-formed-programs-according-to-th) so it probably means either behavior is standards conforming, not very comforting.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour while this case doesn't apply, I would guess in some cases it's difficult or impossible to detect an ill formed program so the standard has to be lenient

Comment: It's very clear what a conforming compiler must do with an ill-formed program. It must diagnose the error, which means issue a warning or error. The reason that conforming compilers aren't required to reject ill-formed programs is so that they can implement extensions while remaining conformant -- just so long as the extensions are designed such that any program using them is ill-formed per the standard.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like:

```
bool b = {2} ;
```

is indeed a *narrowing conversion* if we look at the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `8.5.4` *List-initialization* paragraph *7* says:

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion

and include the following bullet (*emphasis mine*):

> from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type **to an integer type
>   that cannot represent all the values of the original type**, except
>   where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral
>   promotions will fit into the target type.

`bool` can not represent the value `2` so this is a narrowing conversion in the strictest sense.  Which makes sense the whole point of `{}` initialization is to [prevent implicit conversions](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#narrowing) and increase *type safety*. Which the *old style* that you refer to here relies on:

```
bool b = 2
```

which depends on the section `4.12` *Boolean conversions* which says:

> [...] A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value
>   is converted to false; any other value is converted to true. [...]

Of course the whole premise that `{2}` would be a *narrowing conversion* relies the assumption that the value of *true* and *false* is `1` and `0`, which as far as I can tell is not guaranteed in the standard. Although it is implied the only thing the standard promises in *conversions* but if we are going to use a *literal* we don't need to rely on this assumption we have two perfectly good *boolean literals* for this `true` and `false` which is what you should be using.

For completeness sake, this *narrowing conversion* is *ill-formed*, it requires a diagnostic, so either a *warning* or an *error* is acceptable. if we look at paragraph *3*, it says:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as
>   follows:

and include the following bullet (*emphasis mine*):

> Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element of type E and either T is not a reference type or its referenced type is reference-related to E, the object or reference is initialized from that element; **if a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert the element to T, the program is ill-formed**.

and includes the following example:

```
[ Example:
  int x1 {2}; // OK
  int x2 {2.0}; // error: narrowing
—end example ]
```