# "no known conversion" error, even though the conversion operator is written

Tags: c++11, move-semantics, move-constructor

```
struct X {
      X() {}
      X(X&&) { }
};
X global_m;

struct Converts {
        operator X&& () const { return std::move(global_m); }
};
```

I believe the following should work:

```
X x { Converts{} };
```

There is only one single-argument constructor for X. It takes an `X&&`.  The Converts object is temporary, and it converts to `X&&`.  So why do I get this error message from clang-3.3:

```
 // error: "candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'Converts' to 'X &&' for 1st argument"
```

I'm able to explicitly call the operator as:

```
X x { Converts{}.operator struct X&& () }; // this works.
```

Unfortunately for me, it works on [ideone](http://ideone.com/u5Bnqv), which is based on g++ as far as I know.  Is there any online clang compiler that's up and running at the moment?

Comment: I've found clang 3.0 online and it compiled my code (after I made a few, unrelated, changes to support the old code.  Maybe this is just some specific to clang 3.3.  I'm finding it hard to replicate this compilation error online!  Maybe it's a bug in 3.3?  Anybody else able to replicate this?

Comment: It's not a bug read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737929/why-does-bool-b-2-work-well-but-bool-b-2-yield-a-warning-of-narrowing/19737945#19737945) , basically if you have a narrowing in an initialization list it's an illformed program and the compiler must either stop or issue a diagnostic

Comment: Ah!  @aaronman, I've now changed the `{` and `}` to `(` and `)` and it worked.  I'm gonna need to be more careful about `{`.  Thanks for suggesting that might be (part of?) the problem.

Comment: @aaronman I fail to understand why this is narrowing. Here, there are only two user-defined and no fundamental types involved.

Comment: Ok I think this might actually be a better match to your question, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677711/is-it-possible-to-invoke-a-user-defined-conversion-function-via-list-initializat) seems like accepting the code is a bug that has been fixed

Comment: Thanks, @aaronman.  I'll accept if you post that as an answer.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid posted it, have to be honest though didn't fully understand the bug

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of the question @aaronman found.

Comment: @BenVoigt I know, I figured I'd post an answer since he asked me though

Comment: I've also voted to close as dupe.  **But**, I think I like the title on my question.  Other people, who are mystified at the failure to convert, would never think of list-initialization and might never discover the other question and the other answer.  (I guess that's why duped questions aren't deleted.)  Duplicate answer, not entirely duplicate question perhaps? :-)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Yes, I think that's one of the reasons that duplicate questions aren't deleted... each is a new set of keywords and search terms to help find the useful content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677711/is-it-possible-to-invoke-a-user-defined-conversion-function-via-list-initializat) it was a defect in the standard. This is the correction to the standard @ecatmur proposed.

> 4 - However, when considering the argument of a constructor or user-defined conversion function that is a candidate:
>
> - by 13.3.1.3 [over.match.ctor] when invoked for the copying of the temporary in the second step of a class copy-initialization, or
> - by 13.3.1.4 [over.match.copy], 13.3.1.5 [over.match.conv], or 13.3.1.6 [over.match.ref] in all cases,
>
> only standard conversion sequences and ellipsis conversion sequences are considered; when considering the first argument of a constructor of a class `X` that is a candidate by 13.3.1.7 [over.match.list] when passing the initializer list as a single argument or when the initializer list has exactly one element, a user-defined conversion to `X` or reference to (possibly *cv*-qualified) `X` is only considered if its user-defined conversion is specified by a conversion function. [*Note:* because more than one user-defined conversion is allowed in an implicit conversion sequence in the context of list-initialization, this restriction is necessary to ensure that a converting constructor of `X`, called with a single argument `a` that is not of type `X` or a type derived from `X`, is not ambiguous against a constructor of `X` called with a temporary `X` object itself constructed from `a`. *-- end note*]

I don't know if this is exactly how the standard ended up being changed (since I only have a draft) but I would assume something was done because of the change in results depending on the compiler version