# Is it standard-compliant to compile ill-formed program in success?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

For an ill-formed C++ program like:

```
foo^@#$bar%$
```

Is it standard-compliant for compiler to yield compiled binary with diagnostic message, rather than interrupting the compilation as g++/clang++ do?

**intro.compliance** states that:

> If a program contains a violation of any diagnosable rule or an
>   occurrence of a construct described in this Standard as
>   “conditionally-supported” when the implementation does not support
>   that construct, a conforming implementation shall issue at least one
>   diagnostic message.

which does not require compilation error in this case.

Possibly related:

- [What is the C++ compiler required to do with ill-formed programs according to the Standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805394/what-is-the-c-compiler-required-to-do-with-ill-formed-programs-according-to-th)
- [Ill-Formed, No Diagnostic Required (NDR): ConstExpr Function Throw in C++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961181/ill-formed-no-diagnostic-required-ndr-constexpr-function-throw-in-c14?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is legal for the implementation to produce a binary when the input is an ill-formed program. Here is [intro.compliance]/8 in C++14:

> A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do
>   not alter the behavior of any well-formed program. Implementations are required to diagnose programs that
>   use such extensions that are ill-formed according to this International Standard. Having done so, however,
>   they can compile and execute such programs.

In such cases the diagnostic would usually be referred to as a "warning" (as opposed to "error").