# Why warning instead of hard error on ill formed program

Tags: c++, member-initialization, direct-initialization

I'm aware that uniform initialization using braced-init list don't allow narrow conversion (ex double -> int)

but member initialization using init list allows narrow conversion.

```
struct Mem1
{
    Mem1() { cout << "Mem1 - default" << endl; }
    Mem1(int i) { cout << "Mem1 - single arg" << endl; }
};

struct Mem2
{
    Mem2() { cout << "Mem2 - default" << endl; }
    Mem2(int i) { cout << "Mem2 - single arg" << endl; }
};

class A
{
    Mem1 m1 {5.0}; // OK, complier warning 
    Mem2 m2 {2.0}; // OK, complier warning

public:
    A() { cout << "A - default" << endl; }
    A(int i) : m1{1.0}, m2{2.0} { cout << "A - single arg" << endl; } // OK
};


int main()
{
    A a0; // OK
    cout << "-------------" << endl;
    A a1 {2}; // OK
    //A a2 {2.0}; // Error - narrow conversion
}
```

Output

```
Mem1 - single arg
Mem2 - single arg
A - default
-------------
Mem1 - single arg
Mem2 - single arg
A - single arg
```

msvc version - 14.16
Complier issues warning like this for m1, m2 :

```
warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
```

but complination error doesn't occur.

Is it bug or I'm missing something?

Comment: Probably a compiler bug. gcc produces errors, for your cases where msvc emits only a warning.

Comment: Following your advice, I tried building the same code with a newer version of GCC and it gives an error. It seems like a compiler bug. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you know you can use compiler explorer ? https://godbolt.org It allows for very quick testing of a lot of different compilers

Comment: It's very useful to test code like above, thanks.

Comment: [It is legal for the implementation to produce a binary when the input is an ill-formed program. Implementations are required to diagnose programs that use such extensions that are ill-formed according to this International Standard. Having done so, however, they can compile and execute such programs.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46011067/12002570)

Comment: [If the standard says that something is erroneous, or ill-formed, then it requires a diagnostic(which is often just a warning)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22180886/12002570)

Comment: If the program is "ill-formed", the compiler is required to tell you that somehow - issue a diagnostic. After that, it can do anything it likes - including compiling and running the program anyway. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40807628/12002570)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compiler is not required to *fail* compilation of an ill-formed program. Just providing any diagnostic, possibly a warning, is sufficient for standard-compliance. The standard imposes no other requirement on the compiler for an ill-formed program except that it shall provide at least one diagnostic of any kind to the user.

GCC for example also decides to only warn about some categories of narrowing conversions that are ill-formed in list-initialization for backwards-compatibility reasons. (Before C++11 and in C there isn't any such rule about narrowing conversions.)

MSVC is free to decide to only warn about your program and then still compile it as if it didn't contain an ill-formed narrowing conversion. Whether this is intentional choice of behavior or unintended by the developers, I can't tell.

From my tests at godbolt.org it seems that latest MSVC does choose an error instead of a warning.