# Are all unused undefined methods allowed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, virtual-functions, undefined-function

Here’s a class with an undefined method. It seems compilers allow instances of this class to be constructed, so long as the undefined member function is never called:

```
struct A {
    void foo();
};

int main() {
    A a;      // <-- Works in both VC2013 and g++
    a.foo();  // <-- Error in both VC2013 and g++
}
```

Here’s a similar situation, but one that involves inheritance. Subclass `Bar` extends base class `Foo`. `Foo` defines a method `g()`. `Bar` declares the same-named method but does not define it:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    void g() { std::cout << "g\n"; }
};

struct Bar : Foo {
    void g();
};

int main() {
    Bar b;      // Works in both VC2013 and g++
    b.Foo::g(); // Works in both VC2013 and g++
    b.g();      // Error in both VC2013 and g++
}
```

Here's a variation of the above. The only difference here is that `g()` is `virtual` to both `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    virtual void g() { std::cout << "g\n"; }
};

struct Bar : Foo {
    virtual void g();
};

int main() {
    Bar b;      // Works in g++. But not in VC2013, which gives
                // 'fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals'

    b.Foo::g(); // Works in g++, but VC2013 already failed on b's construction
    b.g();      // Error in g++, but VC2013 already failed on b's construction
}
```

See the code comments for contrast of different behavior between VC2013 and g++.

1. Which compiler is correct, if any?
2. Why does VC2013's compiler have some different complaints in its version with the `virtual` keyword compared to the one in its version without the `virtual` keyword?
3. Are unused undefined methods always allowed? If not, what are all the cases in which they're
   not allowed?
4. Does `Bar`’s declaration of `g()` count as overriding
   even when `Bar` doesn't provide a definition?

Comment: The vtable is referenced in the constructor, and it needs the addresses of virtual functions, so VC2013's error seems reasonable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Which compiler is correct, if any?

They are both right. Your code is wrong, no diagnostic required. [class.virtual]/11

> A virtual function declared in a class shall be defined, or declared
> pure (10.4) in that class, or both; but no diagnostic is required
> (3.2).

[intro.compliance]/2:

> If a program contains a violation of a rule for which no diagnostic is
> required, this International Standard places no requirement on
> implementations with respect to that program.

Have a look at your optimization settings for GCC, they may influence the behavior.

---

> Are unused undefined methods always allowed?

A member function must be defined if and only if it is odr-used. [basic.def.odr]/3:

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline
> function or variable that is odr-used in that program; no diagnostic
> required.

Now consider [basic.def.odr]/2:

> An expression is *potentially evaluated* unless it is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5) or a subexpression thereof.
> […]
> A virtual member function is odr-used if it is not pure.
> A non-overloaded function whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression or a member of a set of candidate functions, if selected by overload resolution when referred to from a potentially-evaluated expression, is odr-used, unless it is a pure virtual function and its name is not explicitly qualified.

You are still allowed to use undefined non-virtual member functions inside `decltype` or `sizeof`. But non-pure virtual functions are odr-used simply because they are not pure.

---

> Does Bar’s declaration of g() count as overriding even when Bar
> doesn't provide a definition?

Yes.

Comment: Regarding, `They are both right`, do you mean it's okay for g++ to successfully construct `b` (whose class has the virtual method) while VC2013 cannot, because it's unspecified behavior?

Comment: @CodeBricks It's pretty much identical to undefined behavior. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180312/difference-between-undefined-behavior-and-ill-formed-no-diagnostic-message-requ).

Comment: Does that mean a non-pure virtual function need not be called to be odr-used?

Comment: @CodeBricks Yes. It is odr-used simply through the fact that it is not pure, as stated in the quote.