# When is required instantiation of function template definition?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, instantiation

After I read the answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52388910/5632316), I am still asking question. The answer talks about location of point of instantiation as defined in [temp.point] but it is not evaluated if the instantiations are required.

[[temp.inst]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst) specifies when a function template specialization instantiation is required, the general rule is:

> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, a variable template, a member template, a non-virtual member function, a member class,[...], *unless such instantiation is required.*

Moreover in some paragraph of this section of the standard, instantiation of declaration and instantiation of definition are considered separately.

Let's consider this code:

```
static void Yeap0(int);

template <class T>
void Yeap(T a){
    Yop(a);
}

template <class T>
auto Yeap2(T a){
    Yop(a);
    return 0;
}
namespace x{
    struct y{};
}

int main() {
    Yeap0(0);//ok no definition required here
    x::y ax{};
    Yeap(ax); //the declaration is sufficient, 
    Yeap2(ax); //need to deduce auto => definition required
               //compilation error
    return 0;
}

namespace x{
    void Yop(y){}
}

static void Yeap0(int){}
```

Gcc, Clang and MSVC produce only an error for `Yeap2(ax)`, complaining that `Yop` is not defined at the point of instantiation of Yeap2.

But this error is not generated for `Yeap(ax)`. From basic consideration this seems logical, only the declaration is needed, as for the none template function `Yeap0`.

But the lecture of [[temp.inst]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#4) let me perplex. It could be understood that the instantiation of `Yeap` is also required. But it seems that compilers have taken a more clever path.

Is the compilers behavior an extension?

---

Note: I will not accept the "no diagnostic required" answer. This would be an insult to intelligence: Could one believe that 3 compilers have taken special care to shut down diagnostics for case like `Yeap(ax)` but not for `Yeap2(ax)`?

Comment: Maybe it is not "shut down diagnostics". For `Yeap2`, the compiler has to look into the function, to determine return type. For `Yeap`, it doesn't have to. It is absolutely reasonable that all three compilers behave the same in this regard.

Comment: Obviously compiler devs don't just shut down diagnostics for a special case. The standard uses NDR for things that are impossible/very hard to prove and sometimes in some cases diagnostics are easy for the compiler, and sometimes not. Even EDG has the same behavior.

Comment: @T.C. You should read the standard, compiler are doing the right thing: `Yeadp(ax)` cause overload resolution see [expr.call], which according to [temp.inst]/9 *If a function template or a member function template specialization is used in a way that involves overload resolution, a declaration of the specialization is implicitly instantiated*. The this instantition is performed at the point of instantiation [temp.point] specify where is the point of instantiation: after main, it does not say what is instantiated or if the instantiation is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler complaining really comes from the fact that the function returns `auto`.

In the `auto` case you really hit

> *unless such instantiation is required.*

which must come from the requirement [dcl.spec.auto](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#10).

To verify that assessment you can replace in your code Yeap2 by:

```
template <class T>
auto Yeap2(T a){
    Yeap(a);
    return 0;
}
```

and there is no compilation error.