# Why declaring the size of an array as n, before inputting n, works for the first time but not the second time?

Tags: c++, arrays

I was solving a problem, and I declared the size of an array as n, before inputting n's value and it worked for the first test case but not for the second test case. Why?

> P.S: I couldn't find any relevant information online.

Here is the code snippet

```
    int n,arr[n];
    cin>>n;
```

Comment: I guess your in undefined behavior land, 'n' is not initialized so has a random value, first time it might be 6, next time -3, which is not good.

Comment: My advice is to use a `std::vector` which is the proper dynamic array in the `c++` language. VLAs are not legal in standard `c++`  and have several limitations: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: @Surt That seems helpful but it's working every time for the first test case. Why it's not causing any problem for the first time?

Comment: ***Why it's not causing any problem for the first time?*** Unfortunately some times undefined behavior appears to work as you expect even though you are breaking the rules of the language. This is the worst problem with UB.

Comment: VLAs aside, `n` is uninitialized. It can have any valid `int` value (`INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX`). And that value can change (is random) each time you run the program.

Comment: Relevant reading (also read the linked articles at the end): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: VLAs aside, `n` is uninitialized. It can have any valid int value (INT_MIN to INT_MAX), or accessing it can terminate your application, format your hard drive, email your browser history to your grandmother, or even have nasal demons shoot out of your nose.  Undefined behavior can be annoying that way.  The best you can hope for with UB is that your program terminates.  The worst that can happen is your program appears to work correctly.

Comment: If I drive without a license every time and I've never been caught, does that mean it's legal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int n,arr[n];
cin>>n;
```

This attempts to define a VLA (variable length array). However, VLAs are not part of C++.

This might probably supported as an extension of your compiler (e.g. `g++` supports as an extension).  In that case, you still have a problem. When you define the array, `n` is uninitialized. So it triggers undefined behaviour.

You'd want to read `n` *before* defining the VLA:

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;
int arr[n];
```

Beware that VLAs are allocated on *stack*. So if `n` value is sufficiently large, you will have undefined behaviour due to overflow (= undefined behaviour). For that reason, VLAs are best avoided. You could use `std::vector<int>` instead.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, you are using the value of `n` before initializing it. This is UB.

Additionaly, variable length arrays are *not allowed* in `c++`. e.g.

```
int n;
// compute n somehow
int arr[n];
```

is also not allowed.

If your program doesn't follow the rules of the language, then anything can happen, e.g. working sometimes, working on some inputs, but not others, working on some compilers, but not others, etc. Basically, you can't have any expectations of a program that has undefined behaviour.

Comment: If the program is ill formed, it won't compile. VLA is a g++ extension, while not standard, it's not "anything can happen" .

Comment: @ChrisMM I'm actually confused about that. What about ill-formed-no-diagnostic-required? I was under the impression that compiler is not *guaranteed* to diagnose ill-formed programs.

Comment: @cigien But it works for me, say if you change it to `int n; cin>>n; int arr[n];`

Comment: [VLAs when compiling a C++ source with g++](//stackoverflow.com/a/28421865)

Comment: @KeshavGarg UB means *anything* can happen. e.g. I have a clock that correctly tells me the time twice a day. I wouldn't say it *works* though.

Comment: Arrays have the form: `D1 [ constant-expressionopt ] attribute-specifier-seqopt` (formatting gets lost, sorry), if it doesn't meet that (i.e., the `constant-expression` part), then it's not valid at all. Any compiler (unless using an extension) should generate an error (I don't know of any that don't). The issue here is simply UB, since by using `n` before its given a value.

Comment: @KeshavGarg You cannot experimentally *test* UB. "Works for me in some specific situation" is *not* the same as "is guaranteed by the language to always produce a specific behaviour". And even if your current code does what you expect, the fact that it contains UB means your entire program is invalid and the compiler may generate *anything* for *any* part of it. And modern compilers aggressively exploit UB. It may explode at any time with any minor change.

Comment: ill-formed, no diagnostics required vs undefined behavior (answer also explains difference between ill-formed and ill-formed, no diagnostics required): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180312/difference-between-undefined-behavior-and-ill-formed-no-diagnostic-message-requ

Comment: tl;dr: "ill-formed" requires diagnostics "ill-formed, no diagnostics required" not

Comment: @idclev463035818 That helps, I'll read up on that more. I've edited the answer a bit to match that.

Comment: @cigien It's very common to use `cin>>n` in place of "computing n somehow". So, Why does computing n somehow and then declaring an array doesn't work?