# Mismatched deduction of auto types between different c++ compilers

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, auto, type-deduction

So, I am trying to implement the dot product (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) in some flavour of modern C++ and came up with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class... Args>
auto dot(Args... args)
{
    auto a = [args...](Args...)
    { 
        return [=](auto... brgs)
        {
            static_assert(sizeof...(args) == sizeof...(brgs));

            auto v1 = {args...}, i1 = v1.begin();
            auto v2 = {brgs...}, i2 = v2.begin();
            typename std::common_type<Args...>::type s = 0;

            while( i1 != v1.end() && i2!= v2.end())
            {
                s += *i1++ * *i2++;
            } 
            return s;
        };
    };
  return a(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    auto a = dot(1,3,-5)(4,-2,-1);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

Online: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/kDSney and also: [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=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&insightsOptions=cpp2a,all-implicit-casts,use-libcpp&std=cpp2a&rev=1.0)

The code above compiles and executes nicely with `g++`, however `clang` (and `icc` and `msvc`) choke on it:

```
clang++ ./funcpp.cpp --std=c++17                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
./funcpp.cpp:12:4: error: 'auto' deduced as 'std::initializer_list<int>' in declaration of 
        'v1' and deduced as 'const int *' in declaration of 'i1'
                        auto v1 = {args...}, i1 = v1.begin();
                        ^         ~~~~~~~~~       ~~~~~~~~~~
./funcpp.cpp:28:11: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 
        'dot<int, int, int>' requested here
        auto a = dot(1,3,-5)(4,-2,-1);
                 ^
1 error generated.
```

Now, if I break up the definition of `v1`, `v2`, `i1`, `i2` like:

```
auto v1 = {args...} ;
auto i1 = v1.begin();
auto v2 = {brgs...};
auto i2 = v2.begin();
```

`clang` and `msvc` have no problems, `icc` still chokes:

```
<source>(10): error: static assertion failed

                static_assert(sizeof...(args) == sizeof...(brgs));

                ^

          detected during instantiation of "auto dot(Args...) [with Args=<int, int, int>]" at line 30

compilation aborted for <source> (code 2)

Execution build compiler returned: 2
```

However if I remove the offending `static_assert` then `icc` has no issues compiling the code either.

And beside of the (typical) question: which is right and why :) the concrete question is:

According to `[dcl.spec.auto]` :

> if the type that replaces the placeholder type is not the same in each deduction, the program is ill-formed

`clang` correctly identified that there are two different types defined in the line in question: `'auto' deduced as 'std::initializer_list<int>' in declaration of 'v1' and deduced as 'const int *' in declaration of 'i1'` so I'd like to hear your opinions whether:

- did I hit some undocumented g++ extension considering this specific situation (not mentioned in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/C_002b_002b-Extensions.html#C_002b_002b-Extensions) since g++ to my knowledge correctly handles the different types in an auto declaration list,
- or by any chance g++ did not deduce the two types to be different (... hm...)
- or something else?

Thanks for reading through this long question.
(As a bonus if someone could answer why `icc` fails on the `static_assert` would be great.)

Comment: What's the use of `std::forward<Args>(args)` here?

Comment: test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:4:5: error: inconsistent deduction for ‘auto’: ‘long int’ and then ‘double’
    4 |     auto i = 0l, f = 0.0;
      |     ^~~~

With g++, so it seems it does not extend this in general.

Comment: printing the types gives us:
std::initializer_list<int>, int const*
std::initializer_list<int>, int const*
in g++, so it deduces different types.

Comment: @Evg none, forgot to remove it :)

Comment: GCC [does not compile](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EFmj37) `auto v = { 1, 2, 3 }, i = v.begin();`. Don't understand that it compiles the same insiede lambda. Minimal example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/a5XyxU. It even compiles inside a user-defined functor: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/eYutyK, or a template function: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jnEYXh.

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica I guess it's template-ness causing problems somehow?

Comment: @underscore_d I suppose so. The very minimal example is `template <typename T> void f(T a) { auto v = {a}, i = v.begin(); }`, when invoked, e.g., as `f(1);`. Rewritten as `void f(int a) { /* same body */ }` causes compilation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding from my comments:

g++ does not do this always, consider the example `auto i = 0l, f = 0.0;`, it gives the error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:4:5: error: inconsistent deduction for ‘auto’: ‘long int’ and then ‘double’
    4 |     auto i = 0l, f = 0.0;
```

If we compile your program and print the types of the variables ([with this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c)), we get the following output:

```
v1: std::initializer_list<int>, i1: int const*
v2: std::initializer_list<int>, i2: int const*
```

using gcc version 9.2.0, with flags `-std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra` without any warning or error.

By your comment of the standard this program is ill-formed and the standard [specifies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805394/what-is-the-c-compiler-required-to-do-with-ill-formed-programs-according-to-th) that there should be emitted a diagnostic message (warning or error) unless otherwise specified (which it is not, in this case). Hence I would say that this is a bug in gcc.

It is [a known bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79009).

Comment: Since it's a very convenient bug ... some might argue it to be a feature :D Thanks for your insights!

Comment: It would be great if someone could file a bug against `g++` about this.

Comment: I have never done that before but I can look into it in a few hours.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92509
Hope that is a sensible bug report.

Answer (score 0):

The `static_assert` fail on ICC is definitely a bug. I found a simple workaround by moving `static_assert` into a separate function. Not very elegant solution, but it works.

With slight modifications, this is the code that compiles with GCC, Clang and ICC:

```
template<std::size_t size, class... Args>
void args_no_guard(Args... args)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(args) == size);
}

template<class... Args>
auto dot(Args... args)
{
    return [=](auto... brgs)
    {
        constexpr auto n = sizeof...(args);
        args_no_guard<n>(brgs...);

        using T = std::common_type_t<decltype(args)..., decltype(brgs)...>;
        const T v1[]{static_cast<T>(args)...};
        const T v2[]{static_cast<T>(brgs)...};

        T dot = 0;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            dot += v1[i] * v2[i];
        return dot;
    };
}
```

Comment: Is there a bug against ICC for that? :-)

Comment: You said there's clearly a bug in ICC, so I wonder if they already had a report of this bug submitted by someone. If not, this might be a good time to create one.

Comment: @underscore_d, I haven't checked yet, but I will.